# IIS 8.5: Detailed errors for remote calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a ASP.Net 5.2.3 WebAPI application running on a Windows Server 2012R2 with IIS 8.5.

When I make a local request that causes exceptions in the ASP.Net code, I get a nice, complete error message with stack traces. When I send the same request from another host, I only get a HTTP500 with body `{ "Message": "An error has occurred." }`. I think this is the default behavior.

Now I want to enable these detailed error messages for remote requests, too. I searched around for a few hours already, and found these measures:

1. Edit Web.config

   ```
   <system.web>
     <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
     <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
   </system.webServer>
   ```
2. Enable 'Send errors to browser' in IIS Mangaer (IIS->ASP)

   as described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/670853/iis-8-show-classic-asp-errors-in-browser
3. Enable "Detailed" IIS Error Page settings in IIS Manager (IIS->Error pages->500)

   as described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers

None of which seems to work, so I'm out of ideas by now. 
Maybe it has to do with that my ASP.Net application is hosted in an existing IIS Site. I checked that the above modifications (step 2 & 3) are correctly applied on each level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

To set the error policy in the application, modify the global Web API configuration:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy 
= IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/18/custom-errors-and-error-detail-policy-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Thanks for the hint! - I will try it out as soon as I get to it.. (in some days)